# $(I+vw^T)^{-1}=I -\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv}$ implies $w^Tv=vw^T$

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition

Let $I$ be a $n$ x $n$ matrix, and $v$ and $w$ a nonzero $n$ x $1$ column matrix. Imagine $vw^T$ is nonsingular (therefore $(vw^T)^{-1}$ exist).
Here is my prove:

$(I+vw^T)^{-1}=I-\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv}  \Rightarrow$

$I=(I+vw^T)(I+vw^T)^{-1}=(I+vw^T)(I-\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv})=II+I(-\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv})+vw^TI+vw^T(-\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv})=I-\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv}+vw^T-\dfrac{vw^Tvw^T}{1+w^Tv} \Rightarrow$

$0=vw^T-\dfrac{vw^Tvw^T}{1+w^Tv}-\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv} \Rightarrow$
$vw^T=\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv}(1+vw^T) \Rightarrow$
$(1+w^Tv)vw^T=vw^T(1+vw^T) \Rightarrow$
$vw^T(1+w^Tv)=vw^T(1+vw^T)$ because $vw^T$ is nonsingular: $1+w^Tv=1+vw^T$ therefore $w^Tv=vw^T$

Were am I wrong?

Comment: You can imagine that $v w^t$  is nonsingular, but it will never be so if $n>1$ - this is a rank one matrix.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - isn't $vw^T$ the outer-product i.e. a $n \times n$ matrix, and $w^Tv$ ordinary matrix multiplication i.e. a scalar. How can a $n \times n$ matrix equal a scalar?

Comment: In addition to previous comments, it seems if $I+vw^T$ is invertible, then $(I+vw^T)^{-1}=I -\dfrac{vw^T}{1+w^Tv}$, meaning expanding the way you did should simplify to $0 = 0$ (and not $w^Tv=vw^T$).

Comment: [Sherman–Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula)